# How can I set DataTemplate programmatically in C++/WinRT, WinUI 3

Tags: winui-3, c++-winrt

```
<ListView ItemsSource="{x:Bind MainModelView.GetOrders}">
            <ListView.ItemTemplate>
                <DataTemplate x:DataType="local:OrderInfo">
                    <StackPanel Orientation="Vertical" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" VerticalAlignment="Stretch">
                        <TextBlock Text="{x:Bind OrderAmount, Mode=OneWay}" FontFamily="Consolas" FontSize="12" Margin="4,0,2,4" Foreground="NavajoWhite"/>
                    </StackPanel>
                </DataTemplate>
            </ListView.ItemTemplate>
        </ListView>
```

I know that can be done in XAML, but now I want do this in my code, how to ?

```
DataTemplate dt = XamlReader::Load(LR"(
                    <DataTemplate xmlns='http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation' xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml" x:DataType="Order">
                        <TextBlock Text='{x:Bind Amount, Mode=OneWay}' FontFamily="Consolas" FontSize="12"/>
                    </DataTemplate> 
                             )").as<DataTemplate>();
```

I try this code, but have WinRT originate error: 'The property 'DataType' was not found in type 'DataTemplate'.

Answer (score 0):

We can't use {x:Bind} bindings in code and parse it into xaml. Please try to use {Binding} instead. This is mentioned here: [Creating bindings in code](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/data-binding/data-binding-in-depth#creating-bindings-in-code).

The XAML string should looks like this:

```
    "<DataTemplate  xmlns='http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation' xmlns:x=""http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"" >
<TextBlock Text='{Binding Amount, Mode=OneWay}' FontFamily=""Consolas"" FontSize=""12""/>
</DataTemplate> "
```

Please also check GuYan's answer here: [XamlReader fails to parse DataTemplate with DataType property](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64002978/xamlreader-fails-to-parse-datatemplate-with-datatype-property)

Comment: thanks for reply, I try that way, run with no error, but Order.Amount not show in ListViewItem.

Comment: @Endt4sk Please check if you have assigned the itemssource correctly.

Comment: @Endt4sk Please also remember to assign the `DataTemplate` you got to the listview's itemtemplate property.

Comment: I'm sure I've set the ItemSource and ItemTemplate, but still not work.

Comment: @Endt4sk Please try in a blank project, and share the code your are using

Comment: yes, here is my test project(https://github.com/Endt4sk/winui3-without-xaml)

Comment: @Endt4sk Sorry for the delay, I've test this for a while. I didn't make it either. So I tried to directly use XAML to test instead of create the template in code-behind. But the string thing is that the XAML code works with **x:Bind** but failed with **Binding**. As a comparison, I created a C++/WinRT UWP project to test and the code works both in **x:Bind** and **Binding** no matter the template is created in XAML or code-behind. I'm looking into this behavior.

Comment: If use XAML, it can be done pretty. The project that I provided is without XAML, so I need to find a way that Bind DataType in code.

Comment: @Endt4sk I know that you are trying to do it without XAML. I'm just telling you the Binding markup might be the issue.

Comment: If I use x:Bind in XamlReader::Load method, the application run with WinRT originate error, So I didn't know what to do  : (

Comment: @Endt4sk If you need to use XamlReader to read Xaml String, then you have to use Binding. This is already mentioned in my answer. Now the issue is that the Binding is not working in Win3 C++/WinRT project. I'm looking into this.

Comment: The issue is the 'DataType' not set correctly I think, so the Binding can not found the binding path.

Answer (score 0):

It seems like the original premise is wrong here. I won’t argue with not using XAML, but if you really don’t want to be using XAML – don’t use XAML in code behind either since that goes against the principle you started with. Creating a `DataTemplate` from a XAML snippet is still using XAML. Bindings are also basically a way to connect XAML to code, so you shouldn’t be using those either. If you want to use built in list controls that are mostly designed for use with XAML and bindings – you could probably subclass these and use the `GetContainerForItemOverride`/`PrepareContainerForItemOverride`/`ClearContainerForItemOverride` and generate/bind to the backing data using code instead of XAML’s markup extensions like `{Binding}` or `{x:Bind}`.

If you're not completely opposed to using XAML, but instead want to use code behind to use different templates depending on some logic - consider using `ItemTemplateSelector` instead and/or defining the `DataTemplate` instances as resources in XAML.

Answer (score 0):

I've talked with the team and we could confirm that currectly, there is an issue when using Binding in C++/WinRT. It doesn’t properly detect the [bindable] attribute in C++ projects. Pleaes Use [Microsoft.UI.Xaml.Data.Bindable] instead of [bindable] in the IDL and the binding should work.

Comment: thanks for reply. I've try this way. but still nothing display on ListViewItem